# <apex:input type="date"> is not working in Mozilla

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm using `<apex:input>` tag to display date. It's working fine in Chrome but it's not working in Mozilla.

```
<apex:input type="date" id="dateid">
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`apex:input` component](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_input.htm) is translated into an HTML `input` element in the generated HTML.  The input type of "date" is not supported in Firefox at this time, whereas it is supported in Chrome.

See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: In fact, Chrome seems to have support for more HTML 5 types than any other right now.

Comment: Is their any solution to resolve this issue in Mozilla using apex:input only.

Comment: You could use JavaScript to do feature detection and then provide your own datepicker. Search and you'll find examples such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020950/how-to-make-input-type-date-supported-on-all-browsers-any-alternatives).

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
<apex:inputField value="{!MyDate}" label="My date :" type="date"/>
```

See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm

Comment: Can we use value attribute in <apex:inputfield> tag with controller fields.I think we can use only fields in object level.

Comment: The `value="{!MyDate}"` call the `getMyDate()` controller method. That's what you want to know ?

Comment: If we use inputfiled value with controoler methods it will gives below error..                                    Error: Could not resolve the entity from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!mydate1}'. <apex:inputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

Comment: Yes, your value must return a SObject.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem with the  and I used the  and got the same error which you are getting.

As a workaround what I did is I created an instance of the standard controller record and used its date field as a container to  hold the

```
<apex:inputField value="{InstanceOfObject.AnyDateField}">
```

This way you will be able to hold the input from the page and use it from the Instance in a controller.

Inside Controller:

```
ObjectApi InstanceOfObject {get;set;}
```

Here the Object's Instance will just act as a holder for date inputted from page.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shim/polyfill that will detect whether browser has this feature and will render date picker using Javascript. I had success using this package: [nodep-date-input-polyfill](https://github.com/brianblakely/nodep-date-input-polyfill).

Just include `nodep-date-input-polyfill.dist.js` in your Visualforce page and rest will be taken care.

Note that it will look slightly different than native date pickers.

**Edit:** Here's one more alternative when you need a datepicker but you have no sObject:

```
<span class="dateInput dateOnlyInput">  
  <apex:inputText id="inputFieldId" size="12" value="{!DateStringProperty}" style="width:72px;text-align:center;" onclick="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this, false);" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this, false);"/>  
</span>
```

Further outlined [here](http://salesforcezone.blogspot.co.nz/2013/07/formatting-date-field-in-apexinputtext.html).